# Fuzzy Lookup - DOS screen flashes in 32 Bit mode

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I have added a Fuzzy Lookup to an SSIS package.  When it runs a DOS windows appears, then disappears, then nothing happens.

Changing the project from 32 bit to 64 bit resolves the issue. Why do I have  to run the project is 64 bit mode?

I am using Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the DOS window appearing is the SQLDumper that starts. Unfortunately the Fuzzy Lookup only works with 64-bit in SSIS 2008.
Have a look at the next post for more info.
http://visakhm.blogspot.nl/2012/10/fuzzy-lookup-issues-in-32-bit-runtime.html

There also is a Connect item for this issue:
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/488387/fuzzy-lookup-triggers-sqldumper-even-with-very-small-dataset-with-run64bitruntime-set-to-false